# Mysql query built my phpmyadmin doesn't work in PHP with WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql

Just trying to select all rows with no comments, or comments < 5 characters.

Starting from basics, this works:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM `comments`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

What doesn't work is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comment` = ''";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * from comments WHERE LENGTH(comment) < 5 LIMIT 30";
```

I've put limit 5 because when I do a COUNT on the "empty" comments, it says there's 4 bytes there. The column is not NULL (don't blame me, I didn't write it!)

I've even tried using phpmyadmin to change the "empty" values to the word "chicken", then running

So, I used phpmyadmin to change all the instances of comments < 4 characters to the word "chicken".

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comment` = 'chicken'";
```

As with ALL of the above errors, it spews out:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

But if I do

```
$emptycomment = "chicken";
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comment` = $emptycomment");
```

Invalid query: Unknown column 'chicken' in 'where clause'

WTF?! But that works perfectly in phpmyadmin! (all above tested on stable and alpha versions)

I also saw where someone else put:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comment` = 'chicken'");
```

Again, no dice on any of the above.

The stupid thing is, these all work perfectly directly as a mysql query, and the above were even generated by phpmyadmin!
I've even updated php to 5.3.2, the mysql installed is 5.1.52

I've tried making it EXACTLY as per example 2 here, using variables for everything.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

I've followed the tutorial here:
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Null-and-Empty-Strings/3/

I've browsed about 20 articles here at Stackoverflow.

It's 11:15am. I started at 6:30. Getting a bit frustrated here. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that PHP is only the tool you are using to generate strings that happen to be SQL statements. The MySQL server will never see your PHP code: only the resulting strings. You shouldn't care about PHP until you manage to get a SQL statement that returns the appropriate results.

Answer (score 2):

> $emptycomment = "chicken"; $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment = $emptycomment");

Have you tried to print $query after? You missed quotes around string variable

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($comment) . "'";
```

Comment: Yup, the query echoes back as
Whole query: SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `url` = 'chicken'
But I've also tried: "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comment` = '$emptycomment'" and "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comment` = \"$emptycomment\""

Comment: @talkingnews: again: don't lie. that code cannot give you this query.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Would you like me to to a screencam grab of phpmyadmin producing this code?

Comment: @talkingnews: the only possible way to get help here - is to say what you **exactly** have tried and what results you got. For now all your samples you've taken from your dreams. Again: get php, get notepad, write code, get error, put here code and error as-is, without modifications.

Comment: @talkingnews: I don't need your working PMA, I'm saying that the code you show us cannot give that error or you tried with another code.

Comment: My apologies zerkms, I was trying another column just in case there was "something weird" about "comments", so I had tried the "url" column instead. Still get the same errors. I'm firing up my screencam right now, will let you know youtube URL when done. Apologies for the confusing paste!

Comment: @talkingnews: better - rewrite the question with actual code, expectations and actual result ;-)

Comment: AAARRRGGH! Turns out it was to do with the table having a column name of "url". Change it to "theurl" and everything is OK. I discovered this when I installed XAMPP on my own machine to try it, and everything worked as expected. My shared host owe me an explanation, if not the last 6 hours of my life back. They did a weird thing where you couldn't give tables names with "test" in, too. Thank you both for the suggestions, and I'm sorry if this has wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem where an "empty" field wasn't NULL. What happens if you try the chicken with:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment LIKE '%chicken%'";
```

This will give you a match even if you have CR/LF and other strange "invisible"  characters involved.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the query generated by phpmyadmin puts quotes where I believe there shouldn't be any such as table names and once I remove those it works. I. E. "SELECT * FROM 'db'.'table'" doesn't work but "SELECT * FROM table" does.